# Subscript Out off range vb6

Tags: vb6, subscript

I'm making an antivirus. Now I want my antivirus to change color, so I'm making a form and .ini file (A save). So after a long time coding with Modules and functions. I wan tot test it out until I click the setting form button. I have a subscript out of range error(9).

```
Private Sub GetSetting(Path As String)
Dim Line As String, tmp() As String, ValueX(10) As String, a As Byte
a = 0
If IsFileX(Path) = True Then
    Open Path For Input As #1
        Do
            
            Line Input #1, Line
            tmp = Split(Line, "=")
            If UBound(tmp) = 1 Then
                a = a + 1
                ValueX(a) = tmp(1)
                Ck1.value = CInt(Left(Replace(ValueX(a), " ", ""), 1))
            End If
                If UBound(tmp) = 1 Then
                a = a + 2
                ValueX(a) = tmp(1)
                Ck2.value = CInt(Left(Replace(ValueX(a), " ", ""), 1))
            End If
                If UBound(tmp) = 1 Then
                a = a + 3
                ValueX(a) = tmp(1)
                Ck3.value = CInt(Left(Replace(ValueX(a), " ", ""), 1))
            End If
                If UBound(tmp) = 1 Then
                a = a + 4
                ValueX(a) = tmp(1)
                Ck4.value = CInt(Left(Replace(ValueX(a), " ", ""), 1))
            End If
                If UBound(tmp) = 1 Then
                
                a = a + 5
                ValueX(a) = tmp(1)
                Ck5.value = CInt(Left(Replace(ValueX(a), " ", ""), 1))
            End If
                If UBound(tmp) = 1 Then
                a = a + 6
                ValueX(a) = tmp(1)
                Ck6.value = CInt(Left(Replace(ValueX(a), " ", ""), 1))
            End If
        Loop Until EOF(1)
    Close #1
Else
MsgBox " Read Antivirus Setting is ERROR !" & vbNewLine & "Because the file [ MurderAV.ini ] is not found!", vbCritical, "MurderAV Error"
End If
End Sub
```

The Highlighted part is the ValueX(a) in ck5. (Ck is checkbox)
I'll photo it so it can be clearer:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that each `If` statement has an identical condition:

```
If UBound(tmp) = 1 Then
```

So, as you go through the code, you execute:

```
a = 0
a = a + 1
a = a + 2
a = a + 3
a = a + 4
a = a + 5
```

So `a` is 15, so you have:

```
ValueX(15) = tmp(1)
```

But since `ValueX(10) As String`, you are off the end of the array.

Comment: hey,i have changec my code and now there is just 3 checkbox, and the subscript is now gone. but type mismatch(13) occured, heres the problem:

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/w9XhNh3

Comment: @AdrianTheo maybe you should post a new question for the new code

Comment: @AdrianTheo A "Type Mismatch" is likely coming from your `CInt(...)` call.  Try `Val(...)` instead.  Ultimately, you are probably pulling the wrong sub-String out with the call to `Left(Replace(ValueX(...`, but I am not sure.  Agree, it is a different question, but why don't you just put a breakpoint on the line (click in the Left margin) and then verify the values are what you expect them to be either hovering over the variables, or typing expressions in the "Immediate Window" (e.g., `?ValueX(a)` or `?Left(Replace(ValueX(a), " ", ""), 1)`).  This will let you see the values and debug yourself